# Return List<User> from Firestore Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to return a `List<User>` from Firestore, the problem is that the result of this interrogation is an empty list.
I'm sure that the problem is how I handled the process of add items to an existing list, maybe I didn't wait for them or something like that.

I'll show the code :

```
List<User> readUsers(String path, int limit) {
    List<User> users = [];
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(path)
        .limit(limit)
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) {
      if (snapshot == null)
        print("Snapshot is null");
      else {
        snapshot.docs.forEach((data) {
          User user = User(
            name: data['name'],
            id: data['id'],
          );
          users.insert(0, user);
        });
      }
    });
    if (users.isNotEmpty) {
      users.forEach((element) {
        element == null ? print("") : print(element.id);
      });
    } else {
      print("User is empty!");
    }
    return users;
  }
```

The result of this function is always a `print` of "User is empty".

EDIT :
Data from this function must be stored inside a variable and values must be printed like :

```
try {
List<User> users;
        widget.database
            .readUsers("users", 2)
            .then((value) => users = value);
        users.forEach((element) {
          print(element.id);
        });
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
```

Now the value of `users` is still null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems in your code.

1. Your Firebase call is `async` and does not finish before you test the emptiness of your List `users`. This is why your `List<User>` is always empty. You should define `readUsers` as`async`, and `await` the `QuerySnapshot`
2. If you check the [API of cloud_firestore](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot-class.html), you will see that your `snapshot.docs` is a `List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>`. The data should be accessed
   with the method `data()`.

Try this:

```dart
Future<List<User>> readUsers(String path, int limit) async {
  final snapshot =
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(path).limit(limit).get();
  return snapshot.docs
      .map(
        (doc) => User(
          id: doc.data()['id'],
          name: doc.data()['name'],
        ),
      )
      .toList();
}
```

Comment: Oh well these changes added a new problem. I need to store these data inside a variable, how can I do this? I'll edit the code give me 2 minutes.